# How to avoid re-declaring child methods and still define different methods for different child classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

At the moment, I have a parent class and 2 child classes declared in `Setplay.h`, as such

```
namespace agent {

class Setplay {
public:
    virtual int reset() {return 0;};
};

class ChildSetplay1 : public Setplay {
public:
    virtual int reset();
};

class ChildSetplay2 : public Setplay {
public:
    virtual int reset();
};

}
```

And in a `Setplay.cpp`, I define the methods

```
namespace agent {

int ChildSetplay1::reset(){
    return 1;
}

int ChildSetplay2::reset(){
    return 2;
}

}
```

**Is there a way to avoid re-declaring the methods in the `.h` and still define unique methods for each child?**

If I avoid re-declaring the methods in the `.h`:

```
namespace agent {

class Setplay {
public:
    virtual int reset() {return 0;};
};

class ChildSetplay1 : public Setplay {};
class ChildSetplay2 : public Setplay {};

}
```

Then I get the following error:

> error: no ‘int agent::ChildSetplay1::reset()’ member function declared in class ‘agent::ChildSetplay1’

But I can't define different methods for each child if I change the methods' signature to something like

```
int reset(){
    return ??; // return 1? 2?
}
```

I'm not sure there is a way to do this, but my motives are:

- the actual classes have several methods and re-declaring everything all the time looks ugly
- I still need to keep everything inside the `.cpp` and `.h`

So, **is it possible**? Or are there better alternatives?

Comment: The .h and .cpp need to match so no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the function for every child, so you can't escape this. What you can do, is to go a little bit around and use a `#define` if you have multiple functions
Like:

```
#define SET_PLAY_FUNCTIONS public:\
                           virtual int reset();\
                           virtual int go(); 
namespace agent {

class Setplay {
public:
    virtual int reset() {return 0;};
    virtual int go();
};

class ChildSetplay1 : public Setplay {
    SET_PLAY_FUNCTIONS
};

class ChildSetplay2 : public Setplay {
    SET_PLAY_FUNCTIONS
};

}
```

At least you can save something.....